# Angular iterate Object with name and values

Tags: angular, loops, key-value

I need your help please.

I have a interface with 30 properties. I call a Rest API, written in C#, and get a DataTable back with the results. Now i can convert this result to my interface.

My interface got a name and a value like:

```
PropertyName1:boolean;
PropertyName2:boolean;
PropertyName3:boolean;
PropertyName4:boolean;
```

But, i don't wanna write all 30 properties with {{ object.Properyname }} in my *ngFor.
Is there a way, that i can iterate this object like keyvaluepair?

I tried a keyvalue pipe, but this doesn't work -.-

This is my pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'keyValuePipe',
})
export class KeyValuePipePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, ...args: string[]): any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({ key: key, value: value[key] });
    }
    console.log(keys);
    return keys;
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

i tried a keyvalue pipe.
i expect that i can iterate a object a là keyvaluepair so that i don't have to write every propery for it self.

Comment: Does [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) help get you what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a custom pipe you can use inbuilt [key value pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) something like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of yourObject | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-key-value-pipe-demo-4mkfwl?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I tried it, but this doesn't work.

Comment: My Json is like

[
   {
      "PropertyName1":true,
      "PropertyName2":true,
      "PropertyName3":true,
      "PropertyName4":true,
      "PropertyName5":false,
      "PropertyName6":false,
      "PropertyName7":true,
      "PropertyName8":false,
      "PropertyName9":null,
      "PropertyName10":true,
      "PropertyName11":true,
      "PropertyName12":false,
      "PropertyName13":true,
      "PropertyName14":true,
      "PropertyName15":true,
      "PropertyName16":true,
      "PropertyName17":true,
      "PropertyName18":true,
      "PropertyName19":true,
   }
]

Comment: And then i get as key "0" and as value [Object, object]

Comment: Well, that's probably because your JSON is not an object, but an array containing exactly one entry. In your case you should use `let item of json[0] | keyvalue`

Comment: Oh damn great. u r my hero today :D
I've tried so many things but I wouldn't have thought of it.

Thanks so much!